# Why is my Verilog code generating 'X' in Vivado waveform when two outputs are used to generate a third output?

Tags: verilog, hdl, vivado, waveform

I am currently learning Verilog and digital design to start working with FPGAs, and I am running into an issue. Given a structural design, I was asked to create some Verilog code to simulate it, and ended up writing the following:

```
module prob1Beha(f,g,h,x1,x2,x3,x4);
    input x1,x2,x3,x4;
    output reg f,g,h;

    always @(x1,x2,x3,x4) begin 
        g <= (x1&!x3)|(x2&!x4);
        h <= (x1|!x3)&(!x2|x4);
        f <= g|h;
    end
endmodule
```

In the problem, the outputs `g,h`, are outputs of the circuit, but also inputs to the value of `f`. In order to create a waveform, I made the following testbench:

```
module prob1Beha_tb;
    reg x1,x2,x3,x4;
    wire f,g,h;
    integer i;

    prob1Beha prob1_test(f,g,h,x1,x2,x3,x4);

    initial begin
        for(i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
            {x1,x2,x3,x4} = i;
            #1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

However, when the waveform is generated for specifically the very first entry (`{x1,x2,x3,x4}` = 0000), it correctly generates the value of `g,h` as 0 and 1 respectively, but has the value of `f` being "X" in Vivado.

I believe this has *something* to do with the sensitivity list including only `x1,x2,x3,x4` -- but I thought that if I included g,h, in the sensitivity list, that whenever g,h update as result of updating x1,x2,x3,x4, they would begin to do all the reassignment all over again. I originally thought that writing the assignment in order g,h,f would ensure that once g,h are assigned -- it would then assign f, but I guess I was wrong. What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using recommended Verilog coding style.  To model combinational logic, you should use blocking assignments (`=`) if you are using an `always` block.  And, as you speculated, the sensitivity list is an issue.

A better way to write your code is to remove the `f` logic from the `always` block.  In this case, do not declare `f` as a `reg`, and make a continuous assignment with the `assign` keyword.  You could keep your sensitivity list, but it is better to use `@*`:

```
module prob1Beha(f,g,h,x1,x2,x3,x4);
    input x1,x2,x3,x4;
    output f;
    output reg g,h;

    assign f = g|h;
    always @* begin 
        g = (x1&!x3)|(x2&!x4);
        h = (x1|!x3)&(!x2|x4);
    end
endmodule
```

Or, you could use continuous assignments for all outputs:

```
module prob1Beha(f,g,h,x1,x2,x3,x4);
    input x1,x2,x3,x4;
    output f,g,h;

    assign g = (x1&!x3)|(x2&!x4);
    assign h = (x1|!x3)&(!x2|x4);
    assign f = g|h;
endmodule
```